# eslint-disable no-console appearing in CSS files

Tags: css, sass, eslint

My CSS files have the following comment at the top of them

`/* eslint-disable no-console */`

I don't know why this rule is at the top of the files. Does anyone know what it does?

Answer (score 1):

Yea, its disabling the eslint no-console rule. I think that it use to be on by default in the `eslint:recommend` rule-set, but I don't believe that's the case anymore. At least I haven't noticed it turned on by default. If your not using eslint you can just delete it. If you are using eslint, visit the eslint website and read about configuring the rule. The link is below.

###### [ESLint Docs @ RULE: "no-console"](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-console)

###### FYI *The rule emits an error when you add `console.log()` to your code. Its used mainly to make sure that if you did any troubleshooting using console.log() (a very common practice) that you didn't accidentally leave anything logged that you did not intend to. Of course, as stated above, it is required that you have ESLint as a dependency in your project in order for the rule to have any effect at all, otherwise it is just a useless comment.*